# PYTHON SPYDER starting problem on LUBUNTU

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu, python-2.7, spyder

I installed spyder from software center, but it generates the following error/bug file when i try to run spyder.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/spyder.py", line 2354, in main mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options, args)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/spyder.py", line 2242, in run_spyder main.setup()
     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/spyder.py", line 775, in setup message=_("Spyder Internal Console\n\n"
     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/plugins/console.py", line 56, in __init__ light_background=light_background)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist packages/spyderlib/widgets/internalshell.py", line 119, in __init__ profile)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/shell.py", line 665, in __init__ self.shortcuts = self.create_shortcuts()
     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/shell.py", line 671, in create_shortcuts parent=self)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/guiconfig.py", line 100, in create_shortcut keystr = get_shortcut(context, name)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/guiconfig.py", line 90, in get_shortcut return CONF.get('shortcuts', '%s/%s' % (context, name), default=default)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/userconfig.py", line 377, in get raise cp.NoOptionError(option, section)
 NoOptionError: No option 'Console/Inspect current object' in section: 'shortcuts'
```

It shows this window saying:

```
spyder crashed during last session
if spyder does not start at all and before submitting a bug report, please try to reset settings to defaults by running spyder with the command line option '--reset':
python spyder --reset
```

I ran that command, but there is no difference.

My configuration:

- OS: Lubuntu 14.10 64bit
- Python versions: 2.7.9 and 3.4.2 both installed
- IPython or IDLE starting and working fine

I thought that the problem is in the packages. Then I decided to install anaconda, but it still gives me the same messages.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

İ assume that you are using Turkish as system language. Turn it to English and it should work, than I suggest you do a clean installation.